# What is the purpose of differentiating between norms and metrics?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

A metric $d(x,y)$ takes two points from some domain $X$ and returns a non-negative real number. It is the distance between two points.

A norm $n(x)$ takes only one point from $X$ and 
also returns a non-negative real number. It is the length of a vector when viewed as an arrow from the origin, or simply the distance between $x$ and $0$.

My question is, why is there a need for distinguishing between norms and metrics when a norm is just a metric with one of its inputs being $0$? Is it correct to say that a norm is a type of metric, where one of the inputs is $0$?

Answer (score 5):

A norm *induces* a metric, using $d(x,y) = \|x-y\|$. But a norm is a function $X \to \mathbb{R}$ not $X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$, so in that sense it's simpler.

It only makes sense to talk about norms in a linear space, while any set can get a metric, no linear structure required. In a linear space we see that norms preserve "scale", when we multiply a vector by $2$ its norm is multiplied too, so the size of scalars is then coupled with the size of vectors.

There is a standard way to define a topology (and hence continuity etc.) from a metric space, from a norm we just go via the induced metric as well. So the metric is the more "fundamental structure", as it were.

Answer (score 1):

A metric is, in some sense, more general than a norm.  It might be helpful here to look at somewhat precise definitions:

> *Definition:* Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ (or, perhaps more generally, over a valued field).  A *norm* on $V$ is a function $\|\cdot\| : V \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ such that for any $x,y \in V$ and $a \in \mathbb{C}$, we have
>
> 1. $\| x + y \| \le \| x \| + \| y \|$,
> 2. $\| ax \| = |a| \| x \|$, and
> 3. $\| x \| = 0$ if and only if $x = 0$.

Note that properties (1) and (2) depend on the vector space structure–in order to define a norm on a space, we have to be able to add and scale elements.  If you don't have a vector space structure, then you can't define a norm.  If the only spaces which you have ever seen are vector spaces, then this might seem like a silly condition, but it actually really does matter.

Next, a metric:

> *Definition:* Let $X$ be a set.  A *metric* on $X$ is a function $d : X\times X \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ such that for any $x,y,z\in X$, we have
>
> 1. $d(x,y) \le d(x,z) + d(z,y)$,
> 2. $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$, and
> 3. $d(x,y) = 0$ if and only if $x=y$.

Note that we *don't* need a vector space structure on $X$ in order to define a metric.  Indeed, we don't need any structure at all–we can define a metric on any set at all.  For example, if $X$ is any set, then we could define $d(x,y) = 1$ whenever $x\ne y$ (and zero otherwise in order to satisfy (3)).

That being said, if you have a norm defined on a vector space, then you get a metric for free:  just define $d(x,y) := \| x - y \|$.  It is not that hard to verify that this does define a metric, though some argument is required.

Again, note that a norm is defined only on a vector space, while a metric can be more general.  For example, consider the usual [ternary Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).  We can measure distances between points in the Cantor set using the metric inherited from $\mathbb{R}$.  However, the Cantor set is not a vector space (at least, not as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$–there are vector spaces which are homeomorphic to the Cantor set as topological spaces), hence the metric does not come from a norm.  Indeed, we don't even have enough structure on this space in order to define a norm.

Answer (score 0):

Of course one big difference is the context: We can talk about a metric on any set, while the notion of a norm only makes sense for a (real or complex) vector space.

So say $V $ is a vector space. If $||.||$ is a norm on $V$ and we define $d(x,y)=||x-y||$ then $d$ is a metric on $V$. And $d$ has two extra properties:

(i) $(V,d)$ is a topological vector space

(ii) $d$ is translation-invariant, meaning that $d(x+z,y+z)=d(x,y)$.

Let's temporarily call a metric on $V$ with those two properties a "vector metric".

So any norm  $||.||$  induces a vector metric $d$ via the definition $d(x,y)=||x-y||$, and as you note then $||x||=d(x,0)$.

But the notion of a vector metric on $V$ is still far from "the same as" a norm on $V$. Because if $d$ is a vector metric on $V$ and we define $||x||=d(x,0)$ it does *not* follow that $||.||$ is a norm.